# VSLAM ROS Source Down?

Tags: ros, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to go to download the VSLAM ROS source code found here:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk

Has it been removed or is the site just temporarily down?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252534/vslam-ros-source-down?/) by [aelkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29125/aelkman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`code.ros.org` has been off-line for a long time now.

Looks like [contradict/ros-vslam](https://github.com/contradict/ros-vslam) is a fork of that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0